# Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.company.app/files

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

Not sure why I'm getting this as I thought I followed the example [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) correctly.

Many others have asked questions around this same thing but after looking through the suggestions it's still broken.

The full exception looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.company.app/files/app_videos/VIDEO_20210202_184514.mp4
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
```

The manifest looks like this:

```
      <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

The provider_paths.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <cache-path          name="cache"          path="/"/>
  <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
  <external-path       name="external"       path="." />
  <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <files-path          name="app_videos"     path="files/" />
</paths>
```

The code I am using (pretty much cut and paste from Google's site) looks like this:

```
val imagePath = File(context.filesDir, "app_videos")
Timber.i("imagePath: ${imagePath.name}")
val newFile = File(imagePath, name)
Timber.i("newFile exists: ${newFile.exists()} length: ${newFile.length()}")
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.applicationContext, context.packageName + ".provider", newFile)
Timber.i("Adding Uri: $uri")
```

That last line never executes as the crash happens on the line before it.

Now, I know that I saved the file off here:
/data/user/0/com.company.app/files/VIDEO_20210202_/data/user/0/com.standardandroid.stalkersport/files/VIDEO_20210202_200455.mp4

I know it's there because I can play it back just fine using other code

So, I know the file exists. I just can't create a Uri for it.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: `/data/user/0/com.company.app/files/VIDEO_20210202_/data/user/0/com.standardandroid.stalkersport/files/VIDEO_20210202_200455.mp4` That are a lot of subdirectories. Why again a data/user/0 and so on? Why not `/data/user/0/com.company.app/files/VIDEO_20210202_/VIDEO_20210202_200455.mp4` only?

Answer (score 1):

OK...got it. Needed to tweak a couple things. First the code should look like this

```
private fun shareMultipleVideos(names: List<String>, context: Context) {
    val uris: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()

    for (name in names) {
        val videoFile = File(context.filesDir, name)
        Timber.i("videoFile ${videoFile.name} exists: ${videoFile.exists()}")
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.applicationContext, context.packageName + ".provider", videoFile)
        Timber.i("Adding Uri: $uri")
        uris.add(uri)
    }

    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shared files")
    intent.type = "video/mp4"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    Timber.i("Intent: $intent")

    try{
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context, Intent.createChooser(intent, "Shared Videos"), null)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e("Exception starting activity. \nException was ${e.message}\n Stack trace to follow:\n ${e.stackTrace}")
    }
}
```

Next, the paths xml file needed to be tweaked a bit. Here are the results there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <cache-path          name="cache"          path="/"/>
  <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
  <external-path       name="external"       path="." />
  <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <files-path          name="app_videos"     path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: No. The name is irrelevant. But path="." could work.

Comment: This was absolutely part of the issue. I'll update the solution to clarify that. Thank you for pointing it out!